# C#: приведение к типу Generic <a, b>

Tags: c#, generics, типы-данных

**Ситуация:**

Имеются названия двух типов в виде строки:

```
    string nameTypeInput = activityNamespace + "." + className;
    string nameTypeOutput = activityNamespace + "." + (className.Replace("Request","Response"));

    Type typeInput = Type.GetType(nameTypeInput);
    Type typeOutput = Type.GetType(nameTypeOutput);
```

Требуется приветси объект **result** к типу `ActivityClass< typeInput, typeOutput>`

С этим трудности.

если написать:

```
var rsp = (ActivityClass<typeInput, typeOutput>)request;
```

то получим ошибку:
    **'typeOutput' is a variable but is used like a type**

Как правильно сделать приведение типов?

Спасибо

**Смысл приведения:**

Класс `request` создается рефлексиией и по факту может имет любой тип `(classA, classB, classC`),  но все эти типы - наследуютс от одного базового `ActivityClass<input, output>`.

В этом классе есть метод "`Execute()`"

Соотвественно, класс request приводится `ActivityClass<input, output>` чтобы на выходе сегда получать один объект и выполнить его с помощью "`Execute()`".
Это избавит от последующего определения типа и позволить просто выводить результат выполнения метода.

Comment: `typeInput, typeOutput` - это переменные, описывающие тип, а не сам тип, потому вам выдает ошибку

Comment: ну а как в таком случае указать тип?

Comment: Ваш код выглядит более чем странно. Может, если вы расскажете, что вы делаете и для чего, то можно что то подумать. А так вы чего хотите добиться этим приведением? Вы уверены, что `request` вообще можно привести к тому типу, что вы пытаетесь собрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Если тип неизвестен на этапе компиляции - то вы не можете объявить переменную этого типа.

Лучше всего будет оставить переменную `result` как есть и ничего с ней не делать: объект внутри нее уже имеет нужный вам тип, а большего добиться и не получится.

Но если в таком виде ваша задача не решается, можно сделать следующее:

1. Ввести необобщенный интерфейс, который реализовать в вашем ActivityClass - это позволит использовать этот интерфейс для типизации переменной:

   ```
   var rsp = (IActivityClass)result;
   ```
2. Если вам зачем-то нужен сам тип `ActivityClass< typeInput, typeOutput>` - его можно получить через `MakeGenericType`:

   ```
   var resultType = typeof(ActivityClass<,>).MakeGenericType(typeInput, typeOutput);
   ```

   или узнать непосредственно у объекта:

   ```
   var resultType = result.GetType();
   ```
3. Можно объявить обобщенный метод и вызвать его через рефлексию:

   ```
   static void Bar<TIn, TOut>(ActivityClass<TIn, TOut> result) { ... }

   var method = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Bar", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
   method.MakeGenericMethod(typeInput, typeOutput).Invoke(null, new object[] { result });
   ```

Comment: Просто интересно, вот этот способ вызова метода он быстрее или медленее или то же самое, что если бы вызвать его через dynamic? Я про случай, что если был бы второй такой же метод, что принимает object, то можно было бы просто вызвать `Bar((dynamic)result);` и нужный метод (нужная перегрузка) бы выбрался автоматом в рантайме

Comment: @tym32167 dynamic быстрее при повторных вызовах с теми же типами аргументов, но медленнее при единичных вызовах.

Comment: понял, спасибо )