# С#: Приведение объекта к типу, заданному строкой

Tags: c#, типы, рефлексия

**Добрый день!**

У меня объект **request**:

```
ActivityBasicRequest request = GetRequest(a, b, c);
```

И еще у меян есть тип, заданный строкой:

```
Type typeInput = Type.GetType($"{activityNamespace}.{classParamName}");

//typeInput  is 'ActivityRequest'
```

Нужно объект `request` , который имеет тип `ActivityBasicRequest`, к типу `Type typeInput`.

Я понимаю, что  это нужно сделать с рефлексией, но как, не понимаю.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

В итоге:

Я должен поулчить объект именно ActivityRequest, т.к. я должен именно такой тип передать в конструктор друго класс, `class B {}` `public class B (ActivityRequest param)`

Comment: Можете уточнить что Вы хотите получить на выходе и вообще для чего Вы это делаете?

Comment: Спасбо за ответ, я написал в задаче. Этого достаточно?

Comment: Лучше, но пока непонятно. Вы класс `B` через рефлексию создаете? Если нет, то зачем `ActivityRequest` получать из строки? Напишите также как связаны между собой `ActivityBasicRequest` и `ActivityRequest`

Comment: На большом сайте Вам [дали хорошие комментарии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289944/how-to-convert-object-to-custom-type). В общем, неплохо было бы построить пример, чтобы было понятно какую [проблему Вы пытаетесь решить](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy).

Comment: а вообще `ActivityBasicRequest` может быть приведен к `ActivityRequest`? Вы вот так написать можете? `ActivityRequest request = (ActivityRequest) GetRequest(a, b, c);`

Comment: Я же вчера отвечал уже на похожий вопрос... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879945/178779